# Ordering a list by name

Tags: java, list

i have a list with description of users like this:

```
0_Mary_Rose_maryrose@gmail.com
1_John_Smith_johnsmith@gmail.com
```

How can I order the list alphabetically?

I have this method:

```
protected List<String> ShowUsers() {                                   // show users list
    List<String> allUsersDesc = new ArrayList<>();                                                   // creates list for users description
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, User> user : _userMap.entrySet()) {                                        // scrolls users list
      allUsersDesc.add(user.getValue().getUserDescription());                                        // adds registered users
    }
    Collections.sort(allUsersDesc);                                                                  // sorts by description
    return allUsersDesc;                                                                             // return description list   }
```

and `getUserDescription`:

```
    public String getUserDescription(){
        String description = "" + getUserId() + "-" + getName() + "-" + getEmail() + "-" + getBehavior() + "-" + isActive();
        return description;
    }
```

But like this it is ordering by description and the first item of description is a number, so it is ordering by number and not by the users name.

Comment: Sort your List of users first. Once you have a sorted list of users, then transform it to a list of strings.

Comment: Sort has a second argument for a comparator. You need a custom comparator, which sorts the entries the way you like it. E.g. by first extracting the user name with by using split("_")[1] or any other way.

Comment: Use this: `list.sort((first, second) -> {
   final String firstPart = first.split("_")[1];
   final String secondPart = second.split("_")[1];
   return firstPart.compareTo(secondPart);
  });`

Comment: What if the e-mail-address also starts with a number?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to remove integers and then compare the Strings

```
 Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return removeInt(o1).compareTo(removeInt(o2));
            }
            String removeInt(String s) {
                String num = s.replaceAll("[0-9]+", "");
                return num;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 allUsersDesc.sort(Comparator.comparing(desc -> desc.split("_")[1]));
```